# Listview onClick not working with overlay Framelayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView. Each item of ListView has HorizontalScrollview and    textview. Horizontal Scroll view has images inside it. I am using FrameLayout to display textview over Horizontal  Scroll view(on Left side).

I am able to do it.But when i am clicking on TextView to call on Long Click Listener of ListView ,OnClick event of Image View is triggered .

Here, is ListView item XML file .

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutListViewItem"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <!-- Adding images here programmatically..-->

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>


<!-- Textview That i want to show on left side Above the images in         HorizontalScrollview-->
<gallery.com.activity.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#a0000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    >

</gallery.com.activity.CustomTextView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, Here is my ListView XML file .

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<gallery.com.activity.DynamicListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

So ,how can i call on Long Click Listener of ListView ?
Please help.
Please Let Me know if you want more Clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setOnItemLongClickListener`

```
YourListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {

            //Whatyouwant
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: The Problem is When i am using LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout its working ..

Comment: Got the Solution ... Add android:longClickable="true" in CustomTextView .

Comment: @RajeevKumar Perfect! :) and now maybe my code it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:longClickable="true" into CustomTextView .